# NSNumber & NSDate (swift 3)

Tags: swift, firebase, nsdate

I'm trying to create a timeStamp for sent/received messages to store inside of my database (firebase) and I'm not sure if I'm going about it correctly. Here's the line of code thats giving me an error:

[image: error]

Previously, I would write:

```
let timeStamp: NSNumber = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))
```

but I'm getting the same error:

> "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads"

Comment: The line of code thats not appearing:  let timeStamp = NSNumber(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign an `Int` value to an `NSNumber` variable. You need to create an `NSNumber` from the `Int`. And you need to specify the parameter label:

```
let timeStamp: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))
```

Of course you now don't need to specifically state the data type:

```
let timeStamp = NSNumber(value: Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timestamp: NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber
```

Comment: Please don't forget to explain / comment your code, and provide relevant documentation [from review]